# 少し難解な日本語：不正投票防止の説明文

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

不正投票防止に関する説明文で少し難解な文章がありました。

ページ：
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

原文：

> The votes involved will generally be invalidated as part of an automated process that runs every day and checks for signs of voting fraud.

現在の日本語：

> 関係する票は、毎日実行され不正投票の兆候をチェックする自動プロセスの一部として無効化されます。

日本語案：

```
そのような投票は自動的なプロセスにより無効化されます。
このプロセスは毎日実行され、不正投票の兆候をチェックしています。
```

Answer (score 1):

適用済みです：

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

> 2 人のユーザー間で相互に、またはあるユーザーから別のユーザーへ、継続的に生じる場合、あるいは単に一般的に疑わしいと思われる場合、モデレーターおよび開発者が事態を調査する場合があります。そのような投票は自動的なプロセスにより無効化されます。このプロセスは毎日実行され、不正投票の兆候をチェックしています。票は、調査の後でスタッフによって手動で無効化される場合もあります。票が無効化されると、その票による信用度の獲得または喪失は取り消され、その結果受領者の信用度履歴に「連続賛成投票が取り消されました」または「連続反対投票が取り消されました」というラベルの記録が残ります。